# Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. (Parameter 'Can't make a query on primary keys since number of primary keys...)

Tags: c#, synchronization

I'm trying to use Dotmim.Sync in order to syncronize a postgresql database (server) with a sqlite database (client) and im getting this error while running **agent.SynchronizeAsync()** :

***[InternalApplyChangesAsync]..[InternalApplyChangesAsync]..[InternalApplyTableChangesAsync]..Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. (Parameter 'Can't make a query on primary keys since number of primary keys columns in criteria is not matching the number of primary keys columns in this table')***

I'm not sure why this is happening, since I've successfully syncronized another schema from the same database (18 tables) while having the same configuration for the one schema that it's failing (80 tables).

***Dotmim.Sync.SyncRows.GetRowByPrimaryKeys*** this is the method that it's throwing the exception. For the schema that succeeds, this method is not even called by the sync mechanism.

Comment: You should open an issue on the github repository.
Will be easier to trace, debug and answer